# Defining root_path to access externally

Tags: php, xampp, document-root

I'm building a local web application for my company, and I`m trying to run it in an xampp webserver. My problem is that I want to setup my root folder one time, and reference it in all my files.

For example, my folder structure is as follows:

```
root/index.php
root/include/includefiles.php
root/reles/ajustes/ajustes.php
root/classes/html/menu.php
root/classes/html/rodape.php
root/img/head.png
```

All of my files have to include the files menu.php and rodape.php

Using relative paths I would do `"include ../../classes/html/menu.php"` and `"../classes/html/menu.php"`

Until there it's ok, but in my menu.php file I have a link to other files, and I cannot utilize relative paths to link to it, because at index.php the link would be `"/img/head.png"` and at ajustes.php would be "`../../img/head.png"`

My solution is to define a root path, and I would link all my relative paths to `ROOT_PATH."/img/head.png".`

I found some solutions for this which worked. My problem appears when I try to access my application externally, from another computer using my host IP address, I can access my website, but the link appears as `"c:/xampp/htdocs..."`, and I don't want that, I want the links appearing as `"http://host-ip/img/head.png"`.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice in defining the include paths is to add the `__DIR__` magic constant before the include path. That way the path is always defined relative to the directory of the current file instead of the working directory.

You should have a different root path for public urls and internal server paths. So I'd recommend using the `__DIR__` for includes and other internal server paths and another constant to be used in html and other public paths.

Edit: To clarify: the internal server path is the actual path on the server (www_root/foo/bar) and the public path is the one the server software serves through http (http://example.com/foo/bar)

Comment: I kind undestood, but let me clearify more, i have to include a menu class at all my pages, wich will create a menu with links in it, so at index.php i want to my links to point to the root/page.php, and at the root/reles/ajustes/ajustes.php i want to the links to point to the same root/page.php, so to include the file is easy, but in the included file i want it to point to my root regardless where im at.

for exemple, im my menu.php file i have something like this

Comment: `<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"align="center">
 <a href="'.PHP_ROOT.'/graficos/irpm.php" class="thumbnail" style="width:150px;height:150px " >
   <img src="'.PHP_ROOT.'/imagens/NOPM.png" >
   <b>NOPM</b>
 </a>
  </div>`

then where is the PHP_ROOT i want to replace to my root directory. But as i said, i want this PHP_ROOT point to the root even when im accessing from another computer via my Ip address.

because when i access via localhost all the solutions i found point to c:/xampp/htdocs, but althought this works for access via localhost, this methods doesnt works for remote access.

Comment: Php is executes on the server. Therefore you must use server paths e.g. www_root/foo/bar. The php script generates html that is executed in the browser and everything must reference a public path e.g. http://example.com/foo/bar. It may be confusing since both of these paths may be used as relative paths and therefore even exactly the same in some situations (the foo/bar part of the path)